# Combining SQL WITHs

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a table, customers, it looks sort of like this:

```
CustomerID  cobuyerID
001         005
002         
003         006
004         
005
006
```

Can I use WITH to get a set of customers and a set of cobuyers? So something like:

```
;WITH Customers as
(
   SELECT * FROM Customers where (* WHERE CustomerID not in cobuyerID*)
),
Cobuyer as
(
   SELECT * FROM Customers where (*WHERE CustomerID only in cobuyerID*)     
),
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do it with a LEFT JOIN or an exists...

I don't think though you can have your CTE defined as  customers and select from the customers table... two objects same name seems like the DB engine would get confused.

Here's a left join...

```
;WITH C2 as
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM Customers A
   LEFT JOIN Customers B
    ON A.CustomerID = B.CoBuyerID
   WHERE B.CobuyerID is Null)
),
Cobuyer as
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM C2 A
   LEFT JOIN Customers B
     on A.CoBuyer =  B.CustomerID
   WHERE B.CustomerID is null
)
```